# Проблема с кодировкой Python JSON

Tags: python, json, кодировка

есть программа которая записывает в файл одно слово на двух языках, но в файл записывается юникод. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему.

```
import json

from tkinter import *

from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

from pathlib import Path



file = 'ttt.txt'

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("Добавление нового слова!")



def add_words():
    ru_word = entry_ru.get()
    tu_word = entry_tu.get()
    data = {
     "dictionary": [
    
    ]
    }

    path = Path(file)
    data = json.loads(path.read_text())
    data['dictionary'].append({'ru':ru_word,'tu':tu_word})
    path.write_text(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))

label_ru = Label(text = "Введите слово на русском:")
entry_ru = Entry()
label_tu = Label(text = "Введите слово на турецком:")
entry_tu = Entry()
btn_add = Button(text = "Добавить в словарь!", command = add_words)




label_ru.pack()
entry_ru.pack()
label_tu.pack()
entry_tu.pack()
btn_add.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Поле для ввода и результат записи в файл]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Здесь нет никакой проблемы, всё записывается правильно